# Can't see the expected result in a jQuery lab

Tags: php, jquery, html

The html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Ajax POST</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //disable from default action
    $.post("ex2_5.php", $(this).serialize(), function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        $("#info1").html(data.msg);
    }, "json");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="info1">
Put the textbox input value into this block.
</div>
<br />
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"
id="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The php code:

```
//Establish values that will be returned via ajax
$result = array();

//Begin form validation functionality
if ( !empty($form1))
    $result[0] = "<h1>$field1</h1>";
else
    $result[0] = "<h1>Field is empty!!</h1>";

//return json encoded string
echo json_encode($result);;
```

When I entered the text, it cannot display the same text above the input box. Maybe there have some wrong code, but I cannot find it, please help><

Comment: `.html(data.msg)` : `data` is undefined. You're directly receiving `msg`.

Comment: @user3881958 `echo json_encode($result);;` double semis....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reframed your code. Checkout,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Ajax POST</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("form[id='form1']").on('submit', function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            var th = $(this);
            var data = th.serialize();
            var action = th.attr('action');

            $.post(action, data).done(function(response){
                $("#info1").html(response.msg);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info1">
        <!--Put the textbox input value into this block.-->
        </div>
        <br />
        <form action="ex2_5.php" id="form1">
            <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ex2_5.php**

```
<?php
$result = array();

if (!empty($_POST['form1']))
    $result['msg'] = "<h1>".$_POST['form1']."</h1> is added";
else
    $result['msg'] = "<h1>Field is empty!!</h1>";

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

**Bugs:**
**1)** `;;` double semicolon
**2)** `$_POST['form1']` in your PHP file
**3)** Wrong index using in JS while returning

**Debugging:**
Open console (Right click -> Inspect element -> Console tab) and checkout for errors

Comment: Thanks. Prevented the default behaviour.

Comment: I tried your code. It can show "Field is empty", but when I type text in the input box, it still cannot display the same text..

Comment: Check Network tab (inspect element) on each submit what result you are getting.

Comment: I type some text / don't type anything, it still show Field is empty.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Did you get the expected output yet?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Specify content type for ajax response as application/json. Otherwise the response will be a string not as json.

```
// Specify content type header as application/json
header('Content-type: application/json');

//Establish values that will be returned via ajax
$result = array();

//Begin form validation functionality
if ( !empty($form1))
    $result[0] = "<h1>$field1</h1>";
else
    $result[0] = "<h1>Field is empty!!</h1>";

//return json encoded string
echo @json_encode($result);
```

**Solution 2:**
If header is not application/json then parse string into object using JSON.parse function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //disable from default action
    $.post("ex2_5.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#info1").html(data.msg);
    }, "json");
});
});
</script>
```